# Mesh breaks after using Solidify Modifier

Tags: modeling, solidify-modifier

I'm working on a wave effect using the wave and solidify modifier. See screenshot 1.
This works kinda fine, but the final step is to fill the center hole. As soon as I do that, the center mesh breaks. See screenshot 2.

Any ideas why this might happen?

Mark

[image: State_1 Open Hole]

[image: State_2 Broken]

Comment: Try enabling the even thickness checkbox in the modifier

Comment: perhaps after filling it's no longer manifold, e.g. because you keep the internal faces.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. @Akshay2005 Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady What do you mean? The second screenshot shows the pentagon filled, which results in breaking it. Do you mean the topology is lost/changed after filling? How can I keep it in tact?

Comment: @MarcusMaximus do you know what "manifold" means? https://www.sculpteo.com/en/3d-learning-hub/create-3d-file/fix-non-manifold-geometry/